# Adding cells in two ranges which are located at two different sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I am trying to sum corresponding cell values in two ranges and replace the values in one of the ranges with the sum . See my code snippet below:

```
For i = 1 To daterow.Rows.count - 1
    If (outinter - diff) > 0.5 Then
         diff = diff + DateDiff("n", Indt(i - 1), Indt(i))
         Y = Sheets("output").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
         Set inputRng = Sheets("Input").Range(Sheets("Input").Cells(i, 7), _
                        Sheets("input").Cells(i, ngag + 6))
         Set outputRng = Sheets("Output").Range(Sheets("Output").Cells(Y, 6), _
                        Sheets("Output").Cells(Y, ngag + 5))
         outputRng.value = Evaluate(outputRng.Address & "+" & inputRng.Address)
    Else
         'Some Code here
    End If
Next
```

So, I set up two ranges (inputRng and outputRng) in lines 5 and 6. inputRng is from sheets("Input") and outputRng is from Sheets("output"). When I run the code, the "Evaluate" function (line 7) sums the ranges but here is the problem:

Both ranges are derived from the same sheet and since I am in sheets("input") during this computation, values for both inputRng and outputRng are derived from sheets("input"). When I rewrite line 7 as follows:

```
sheets("output").outputRng.value = Evaluate(sheets("output").outputRng.Address _
                                  & "+" & sheets("input").inputRng.Address)
```

I get an error message "Object does not support this property or method". Is there any other way to force the code to read the outputRng from my Sheets("output")?

I could loop through each cell and sum the values, but it would take a long time to run the code as this macro has to handle a lot of data.

Any thought will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for looking into it.

MPD

---

**Solution**

Oops, the server did not let me answer the question, So, I am posting the solution here instead:

Thanks everyone for your input. In fact Excellll's last comment clicked my mind! So, here is how i got it working:

```
Dim value() As Variant
Dim shtIn As Worksheet, shtOut As Worksheet
Set shtIn = Sheets("Input")
Set shtOut = Sheets("Output")
Redim Value(daterow.Rows.count - 1)

For i = 1 To daterow.Rows.count - 1
    If (outinter - diff) > 0.5 Then
      diff = diff + DateDiff("n", Indt(i - 1), Indt(i))
      Y = shtOut.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
      Set inputrng = shtIn.Range(shtIn.Cells(i, 7), shtIn.Cells(i, ngag + 6))
      Set outputRng = shtOut.Range(shtOut.Cells(Y, 6), shtOut.Cells(Y, ngag + 5))
      value = Evaluate("Output!" & outputRng.Address & "+" _
                  & "Input!" & inputrng.Address)
      shtOut.Range(shtOut.Cells(Y, 6), shtOut.Cells(Y, ngag + 5)) = value
    Else
      'Some Code here
    End If
Next
```

So, instead of writing out the sum into a range in another sheet, I stored that into an array and later transferred the array into the Output Range which I could do without looping.

Comment: I'm still looking at it, but the very first thing I can tell you is that your error message comes from the fact that (for instance) `outputRng` is a local variable -- it is *not* a property of the "output" sheet. `sheets("output").outputRng` does not exist, hence `Object does not support this property or method.`

Comment: I agree! In the spreadsheet itself (not using vba), we can use named ranges and use range properties from other sheets too. There should be a way to use VBA and read the values from ranges located at another sheet. Just couldn't figure out how .....

Comment: +1 for following up and providing the solution. =D

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this at line 7 instead?

```
 outputRng = outputRng.Value + inputRng.Value
```

EDIT:

You could do yourself a favor for debugging's sake by declaring a couple of Worksheet objects and a couple of Range objects.

```
Dim shtIn As Worksheet, shtOut As Worksheet
Dim rngIn As Range, rngOut As Range
Set shtIn = Sheets("Input")
Set shtOut = Sheets("Output")
Set rngIn = shtIn.Range("Input")
Set rngOut = shtOut.Range("Output")
```

Then use these ranges in your code instead of the repeated `Sheets("...").Range("...")` constructions.

Comment: Excellll, Thanks for the response. I had infact tried that before posting this question. I get an error message "Type Mismatch" with it.

Comment: Agree!! That is a good idea and I will use it in the code. Problem still unsolved though.

Comment: I still think you should do away with the Evaluate() altogether. Anyhow, the issue with line 7 is that .Address will return only the cell reference, e.g., "$A$1", without the sheet reference (which you need for that to work), e.g., "'Input'!$A$1".

Comment: Thanks Excelll!!! You gave me an idea. It's now working!! Great! I have edited my original post.